# "ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with" error returned when trying to save a form on Admin

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-forms, djongo

I have an `ArrayModelField` on my `Document` model but when I tried to save the values on the `Admin`, it returned with a `['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` error. I've been googling this error and it only shows up when `formsets` are used, but I haven't even used `formsets` here. I think my syntax is correct with `files` having both `model_container` and `model_form_class`. The `DocumentForm` class is just the usual form class with fields `__all__` so `files` field is already included. Am I missing something? Or should I rewrite my `DocumentForm` code and use `formsets` instead?

```
class Document(TimestampedModel):
    files = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=DocumentFile,
        model_form_class=DocumentFileForm,
        default=[],
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DocumentFile(TimestampedModel):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file = models.FileField(
        _('File'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None
    )
```

Comment: Formsets are used internally by djongo to represent ArrayModelField and ArrayReferenceField. You are not the only one with this problem as there is an open [issue](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/164) on djongo github page.

Comment: Btw, it seems strange for me that you've marked Document model as abstract - this means that there is no Documents collection in your database (as I understand this), but there is a DocumentFiles collection. Is it a behaviour you intented to have?

Comment: @RomanYakubovich Oh thank you for clarifying that out! I bumped into that opened issue in github but since there was no solution yet so I looked for other way to implement it which I thought was to use formsets. Now I know djongo already did that for me, thanks to you. Do you know any other way to successfully implement nested forms with mongodb as db?

Comment: @RomanYakubovich Regarding my Document model being abstract, I had the same question as well since this is already an existing code base. But I think because it's also a field in another model and it's basically just saved there instead of creating a table solely for it. The DocumentFile, I'm the one who added it and didn't make it abstract since it's not saving the values I was adding through REST endpoints